# Horizontally centering a table-cell within a table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a table-cell to be centered within a page, and none of the usual tactics have worked; I've tried, specifically, different approaches to text-align and margin: auto, all with no luck.

Does anyone see where I'm going wrong? Here's my code:

```
<div class="table col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 20px; width: 100%; "> 
    <h3 class="text-center col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 200px; color: #dcdcdc; background-color: #333333; height: 30px; vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell; ">
        Your account is currently pending. Please check back in again later.
    </h3>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/corduroy_joy/yvzaa0kx/7/), if that helps.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is it this entire element you're trying to get centered on the page? If so, the parent element of this is important, you have width 100% on it.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. Yes, I want this entire element centered on the page. I just tried removing the parent's width attribute, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute;` from your `.centered` class, delete the wrapper div and apply `.centered` directly to div with `.table` class.

HTML:

```
<div class="table col-xs-12 centered" style="margin-top: 20px;  "> 
    <h3 class="text-center col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 200px; color: #dcdcdc; background-color: #333333; height: 30px; width: 100% !important; vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell; ">Your account is currently pending. Please check back in again later.</h3>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.centered {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-10%);
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/KdGoxg?editors=011)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. While this centers the text, the table-cell is now covering up the text below it. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I only see this ``Your account is currently pending. Please check back in again later.`` as text in your code. Can I see the complete code so I can help you?

Comment: Sorry for that. Here's [the whole page](http://jsfiddle.net/corduroy_joy/yvzaa0kx/7/).

Comment: check the updated pen, are your trying to move the content below ``.table`` up as well?

Comment: I'm not positive this answers your question, but I want the alert to be its own centered line and for all the subsequent text to appear beneath that line.

Comment: that's how it appears on my edited pen, is that your idea?

Comment: The fiddle is distorting a few things, but [this is basically what I'm after](http://jsfiddle.net/corduroy_joy/yvzaa0kx/14/). I've used the sadly missed <center> tag here in place of the .centered class div. Of course, I'm looking for a way not to use the <center> tag, as I hear that's frowned upon these days.

Comment: bootstrap has too very cool classes for centering. ``text-center`` & ``center-block``

Comment: I just updated my answer and pen, is this how you want it?

Comment: Yes, the code pen looks great, but for some reason I can't get it to work with my code; I changed the css and the html and even cleared the cache. I'm going to keep massaging the code and see if I can get it to work. (Incidentally, when I put my new code into code pen, it looks right :-/)

Comment: try copying and pasting my pen into your project.

Comment: well copying all of it into my project won't actually work, because it's a visual studio/asp/mvc site with a lot of razor/c# in it. What I shared was the page source post-compilation.

Comment: damn... hopefully it's something minor. I don't know much of VS.

Comment: Well since this looks right in the codepen, I'll mark it as solved for now. Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: No problem. If you need any additional help just message me!